# Opening a file chooser in the primary window - Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am able to open the file chooser with the following code

```
    @FXML
    private TextField myText;

    @FXML
    private Button browse;
    private Window primaryStage;


    @FXML
    private void initialize(){

        browse.setOnAction((event) -> {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            String fileName = String.valueOf(file);
            myText.setText(fileName);
        });

    }
```

But I am trying to open the file chooser something like this (screenshot of Microsoft updater)
[image]

Can anyone tell me how should I open the file chooser as shown in the screen shot (like a top layer)?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you open the file chooser?

Comment: A file explorer to choose a file

Comment: You want something like this? http://i.imgur.com/nPSBdHk.png Notice how the file chooser is "attached" to my "Test" window.

Comment: exactly, thats what I was looking for

Comment: @akshay Ah, I see the problem. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your file chooser is not being attached to your `primaryStage` is because `primaryStage` is `null`. You never set its value. When such parameter is `null`, the file chooser will float around without a parent.

So your solution would be to actually set `primaryStage`. But if you want a quick solution, replace `File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);` with this:

```
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(((Node) event.getTarget()).getScene().getWindow());
```

Comment: would you be able to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940507/opening-a-new-fxml-attached-to-the-current-stage-javafx

Comment: @akshay yeah, I've posted an answer there.