# Opening a new FXML attached to the current stage - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

This is an extension of an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939476/opening-a-file-chooser-in-the-primary-window-javafx) in which a file chooser opens and is attached to the primary stage.

How would one go about opening an `FXML` stage attached to the the primary stage?

The code below loads the `FXML` and replaces the primaryStage (current stage). How can I load it as an attached window instead?

```
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Node) event.getTarget()).getScene().getWindow();
            Parent parent = null;
            try {
                parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/GUpdater-progress.fxml"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent,600,400);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setTitle("GUpdater");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want to create a new stage?

Comment: Yes, would I be able to attach it to the primary stage?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "attach". Do you mean you want the existing stage to be its [owner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) (scroll down to the "Owner" section of the docs)?

Answer (score 0):

Given your previous question, I imagine that by "attach" you mean something like what the File Chooser does (when there is a parent, the File Chooser will follow it around).

The first thing you need is the "main window", which you can get via

```
       Window ownerWindow = ((Node) event.getTarget()).getScene().getWindow();
```

The next thing is to actually load your new stage.

```
       Stage stage = new Stage();
       stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
       stage.initOwner(ownerWindow);
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/GUpdater-progress.fxml"));
       Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
       stage.setTitle("GUpdater");
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
```

The key is the `stage.initOwner(ownerWindow)` part. This new stage you are creating is "owned by" the original window, which is `ownerWindow`.

In addition, if you want to achieve a feel more like the File Chooser's, you should use

```
       stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Before `setScene()` is called. This will remove the border.

Comment: I tried it but I get the stage as a pop up but not attached.

Comment: @akshay what happens when you move the original window? Both windows should move around (that's the effect of ownership) - if they do, then I'm not quite sure what you mean by "attached" anymore.